# Questions about necessary steps for building GCC

Tags: gcc

I have a few questions about the build process for building GCC that i was hoping someone could explain to me.

1. Why is it necessary to unset `C_INLCUDE_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH LIBRARY_PATH`
2. Why does GCC require `MPFR`, `MPC`, and `GMP` to build? And if old versions (as downloaded with the `download_prerequisites`) and then newer versions are installed later, which will be used by a compiled program?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does GCC require MPFR, MPC, and GMP to build?

I can answer this part. MPFR and MPC are necessary to apply floating-point operations at compile-time. In theory MPFR could be used to parse decimal constants in the source code (GCC developers have said several time that since they depend on MPFR now, they might as well use it for that but to my knowledge, GCC's decimal-to-floating-point conversion still relies on their own code in [real.c](http://www.exploringbinary.com/how-gcc-converts-decimal-literals-to-floating-point/)). Using MPFR also allows to make cross-compilers hosted on a machine that doesn't have floating-point (or has floating-point with different characteristics than the target architecture).

GMP is just a dependency of the other two.

It used not to be like this, the dependency towards MPFR is a relatively recent change (say a couple of years).

---

> And if old versions (as downloaded with the download_prerequisites) and then newer versions are installed later, which will be used by a compiled program?

The GMP, MPFR, MPC libraries are used at compile-time only. Any program that has already been compiled was compiled with the version of these libraries that the compiler used at that time. It doesn't change anything from the point of view of a compiled program if you update the library afterwards.

---

While I'm here, I think I can explain the other thing as well:

> Why is it necessary to unset C_INLCUDE_PATH CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH LD_LIBRARY_PATH LIBRARY_PATH

Because the build process uses these variables for its own purposes and it will mess it up if you set them.

Comment: I think I may have worded my question about `download_prerequisites` poorly. I meant that if GCC is built with old versions of those programs. But newer versions have been installed on the system, when GCC compiles a program (`a.out` for example); will `a.out` by built using the newer versions that are installed on the system?

Comment: @chewsocks The binary inspection tool on your undisclosed system (that would be `otool` on Mac OS X) will tell you if these libraries are linked dynamically to the compiler binary. This is sure to depend on the host system being used. Note that `gcc` is probably not the compiler binary but a so-called “compilation driver”.

Comment: @chewsocks Because `atof` on the host may be of poor quality (conversion from decimal to floating-point is harder than it looks). GCC wants to say in its documentation that floating-point constants are rounded to the nearest representable number, not that they are rounded to the nearest representable number unless you are using it on platforms X and Y.